# Listbox, selected item and lost focus highlight style

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, styles, selecteditem

I know there is tons of these questions out there. But most of these solutions don't work in my situation. However after spending a day on it, I finally found a solution which works in my case. I just need somebody with deeper knowledge of XAML to explain to me and possibly the others what exactly happens here.

```
 <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyleNoHighlighting" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

If somebody out there needs the xaml of how to use it, here it is

```
  <ListBox Background="Transparent"
           BorderThickness="0"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding MenuSubItems}"
           SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"
           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyleNoHighlighting}">
```

So what is happening in that style? I haven’t seen anything like this before. After some research I found out that TemplateBinding is just setting up its values to the parent. Then why is that ContentPresenter even needed if it does not add anything to the style. It's worth to mention that without ContentPresenter, it simply does not work.

Kind Regards 
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of ContentPresenter is quite simple – it is a placeholder for any XAML content and it can be used to insert content at runtime.

[Here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/what-contentpresenter) is more.